# System.Data.DataSetExtensions in Mono

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, mono, datasetextensions

I believe the following should work:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> d = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();
```

But it doesn't! I get:

> Error CS1061: Type `System.Data.DataTable` does not contain a definition for `AsEnumerable` and no extension method `AsEnumerable` of type `System.Data.DataTable` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` as a reference and this is Mono 3.5 and MonoDevelop 2.4.2. I also have

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's your problem and cannot test now but I would definitely start with trying to call extension method directly:

```
var rows = DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(myDataTable);
```

This will give you some insight on what *exactly* fails, if this is a namespace, class or method problem.

By the way, **[there is no Mono 3.5](http://www.mono-framework.com/OldReleases)** so you might really be using an old version.
Current version is [2.10](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

Mono versions don't go along with .NET version numbers, however you can expect Mono 2.10 to support most of the LINQ goodness (at least for `DataSet`).

Comment: I guess by mono 3.5 I meant the one compatible with most of .NET 3.5

Comment: @Ben: there are plently of Mono versions **compatible with .NET 3.5 on different levels** so it's always good to know the exact version when hunting down a problem.